# Python Round Function Issues with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, rounding

I am relatively new to spark and I've run into an issue when I try to use python's builtin round() function after importing pyspark functions. It seems to have to do with how I import the pyspark functions but I am not sure what the difference is or why one way would cause issues and the other wouldn't.

Expected behavior:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions
print(round(3.14159265359,2))
>>> 3.14
```

Unexpected behavior:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
print(round(3.14159265359,2))
>>> ERROR

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-50155ca4fa82> in <module>()
      1 from pyspark.sql.functions import *
----> 2 print(round(3.1454848383,2))

/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in round(col, scale)
    503     """
    504     sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
--> 505     return Column(sc._jvm.functions.round(_to_java_column(col), scale))
    506 
    507 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

Comment: I think you need to initialize a spark context before using this function. In the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm' ==> sc is NoneType ==> SparkContext does not exist.
The first case works because it still uses the native round function, if you want to use the pyspark function you would have to call pyspark.sql.functions.round(3.14159265359,2)

Comment: But that is the thing, I don't want to use the pyspark round function. If I do the 'from pyspark.sql.functions import *', it is almost as if pyspark is overloading the round() function...?

Comment: @MGriggs *"it is almost as if pyspark is overloading the round() function...?"* Thats **exactly** what it's doing. How else do you expect `import *` to work? Please read [why is `import *` bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` to avoid conflict.

In this way, you can use all python built-in functions normally and when you want to use pyspark functions, use them as `F.round`

Comment: I put an answer below to how to use a DataFrame.  After seeing this answer I realize I misunderstood the question.  importing functions as F is common practice.  You can also reference python round with `__builtin__.round()` but that's ugly.  Deleting my bad answer.

Comment: OP mentions specifically in his comment that he doesn't want to use pyspark functions. True, that does makes it ugly and perhaps i think it is better to go with the common practice :)

Answer (score 5):

Don't do import * as it can mess up your namespace.

Pyspark has round function:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.round

So build-in function `round` is being replaced by `pyspark.sql.functions.round`

Answer (score 4):

If you have a long piece of code where you have used pyspark.sql.functions without any reference like F. Then inorder to use python round exclusively, you can use `__builtins__.round()` in pyspark code. @michael_west was almost right but the module should be `__builtins__` instead of `__builtin__.` Example code:

```
from builtins import round

k = round(123.456)
```

Comment: I was about to head down the path of fixing all the places where someone else's code uses `pyspark.sql.functions.round` so I can use the built-in `round`, but had forgotten about the existence of the `builtins` module. On a deadline, and pressed for time, it is way easier to `import builtins` and later call `builtins.round`, so thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, and I don't want to alias pyspark.sql.functions so just alias the round here.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import round as sqlround
```

Comment: Is this a solution or are you saying you have a similar problem?

Comment: @Ruli this looks like a valid solution to me.

Comment: @mck yes but description is a little confusing, that's why the question

Answer (score 0):

to resolve the issue use the following code /way

```html
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
```

Here, use 'func' to let compiler know that use 'round' function from pyspark.sql.functions and not the native one.

Sample usage down below

```html
display(df_film.withColumn('HourLength', func.round(df_film['Length']/60,2)))
```